# How to disable Next.js cache in server-side component

Tags: caching, next.js, axios, server-side-rendering

I am facing an issue. I am using Next.js SSR (Server-Side Rendering), and when I run 'npm run dev,' everything works fine. However, when I build Next.js and run 'npm start,' the API response is cached by Next.js. So, when I refresh the page, the response remains exactly the same. I want to receive new data from the API every time I refresh the page.

code

```
// app.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Joke from '../utils/jokeapi';

const Home = async () => {
  const data = await Joke();
  console.log('data', data);

  return (
    <div className="p-5 pt-10">
      <h1 className="text-5xl p-5">Welcome Jokes HUB</h1>
      {data.map((joke: Joke, index: number) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} className="p-5">
            <h1 className="text-3xl">{joke.joke}</h1>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

//jokeapi.tsx

import axios from 'axios';

const Joke = async () => {
  const Backend = process.env.SERVER || 'http://localhost:3001';
  console.log('backend', Backend);
  const Response = await axios.get(`${Backend}/api/jokes`);
  const jokeData = Response.data;
  return jokeData;
};

export default Joke;
```

I used the 'cache: no-cache' on my Axios, but it's not working. I checked that 'cache: no-cache' with the Fetch API without Axios, and the same thing is not working."

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question in my search while I'm also having some hard times with the Next data caching, that can be really confusing sometimes.

Did you try to use these ?

`export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`
doc : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic

or `export const revalidate: 0`
doc : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#revalidate

I found this in my search too : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_noStore